# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable error invoking find_element on soup object using Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I want to write comment on some posts with selenium with python.
Here is my code:

```
html=driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
input=soup.find_element_by_css_selector("body > div._2dDPU.CkGkG > div.zZYga > div > article > div.eo2As > section.sH9wk._JgwE > div > form > textarea)
input.clear()
input.send_keys("blahblah")
input.submit()
```

Here is the error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-250a282801db> in <module>
----> 1 input=soup.find_element_by_css_selector("body > div._2dDPU.CkGkG > div.zZYga > div > article > div.eo2As > section.sH9wk._JgwE > div > form > textarea")
      2 input.clear()

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup is just a parser, you can't send or click items with it. That's all under selenium. Your code is mixing selenium methods with BeautifulSoup methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the line of code:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
```

`soup` is a [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) type object, which represents the document in a data structure.

Where as [`find_element_by_css_selector()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_css_selector) is a [WebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_css_selector) / [WebElement](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) method.

So you won't be able to invoke `find_element_by_css_selector()` on **`soup`** which is a *BeautifulSoup* type object. Hence you see the error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Ideally, you need to invoke `find_element_by_css_selector()` on the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://example.com/")
input=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > div._2dDPU.CkGkG > div.zZYga > div > article > div.eo2As > section.sH9wk._JgwE > div > form > textarea)
input.clear()
input.send_keys("blahblah")
input.submit()
```

Comment: i actually i already downloaded that selenium package and webdriver module

Comment: my code works well when i log in to my instagram account

Comment: but it makes error when i input some contents to typeArea
i think there is some differet way with iput_type to access to typeArea

Comment: @codenewbee Sounds like a different issue all together. Can you raise a new question as per your new requirement? Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.